# Why Log4net add "System.Exception" to each line?

Tags: .net, log4net

Log4net add "System.Exception" to each lin in the log

---

DEBUG 2014-08-12 12:46:02,446 [12] [OnSubscribe] Subscribe: **System.Exception**: Accounts

DEBUG 2014-08-12 12:46:55,494 [7] [Dequeue] Start Dequeue **System.Exception**

---

this is the layout configuration

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %d [%thread] [%c] %message " />
</layout>
```

I need to remove this "System.Exception"

Comment: How do you call `log.Debug()`?

Comment: log.Debug(message, new Exception(exceptionData)); 

I think I get it :D 

I have two cases:
first: log message
second: log message and exception

I need to add condetion to use log.Debug() with message only.